# Conda update on Windows 7 failing with import error of yaml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

On Win7 64 bit, with Anaconda 1.7, when I go to the command prompt and try:

```
conda update conda
```

I get the following error.

> Error: could not import yaml (required to read meta.yaml files of conda recipes)

All conda commands give the same error. For example:

```
c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli>conda update conda
```

Where do I start to fix this, please? I don't think this is a PATH problem as I can see:

> PATH = ...C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi...\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27

Comment: What does conda info and conda list show?

Comment: Can you run `conda install pyyaml`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to fix this was to search for yaml and manually add it to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, e.g.

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\Anaconda\pkgs\pyyaml-3.10-py27_1\Lib\site-packages
```